# print the strings in vertical format in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
     String add_space(s,temp)//for adding the space so as to make all the strings equal
    {
        int to_add= max-s.length();
        String blank=" ";
        for(int i=0;i<to_add;i++)
        {
            blank=s+blank;
        }
        return blank;
    }
    
    void manipulated_array(str, n,max)
    {
        int temp=max;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String s=str[i];
            str[i]=add_space(s,temp);
        }
        for(int j =0;j<n;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(str[j].charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Main obj = new Main();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String str[]= new String[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            str[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        
        {
            int max=str[0].length;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(max=str[i].length())
                  max=str[i].length();
                
            }
            obj.manipulated_array( str, n, max);
          //  add_space(String str[],max);
          
        }
        
    }
}
```

i am to trying to solve this question refer here:

https://10yearsquestionpaper.com/isc/computer-practical-question-paper-2019.html

i am getting 5 errors:

```
Main.java:11: error:  expected
     String add_space( s,temp)//for adding the space so as to make all the strings equal
                        ^
Main.java:11: error:  expected
     String add_space( s,temp)//for adding the space so as to make all the strings equal
                             ^
Main.java:22: error:  expected
    void manipulated_array(str, m,ma)
                              ^
Main.java:22: error:  expected
    void manipulated_array(str, m,ma)
                                 ^
Main.java:22: error:  expected
    void manipulated_array(str, m,ma)
                                    ^
5 errors
```

Comment: You have to declare types for the parameters. Ex: `String add_space(String s, String temp) { ... }`

Comment: Main.java:56: error: '.class' expected
      obj.manipulated_array(String []str,int n,int max);
                                     ^
Main.java:56: error: ';' expected
      obj.manipulated_array(String []str,int n,int max);
                                        ^
Main.java:56: error:  expected
      obj.manipulated_array(String []str,int n,int max);
                                               ^
Main.java:56: error: ';' expected
      obj.manipulated_array(String []str,int n,int max);
                                                      ^
4 errors

Comment: ...but you don't declare the types when calling the functions. Ex: `obj.manipulated_array(str, n, max);`